# Parsing files and checking if value exists before indexing, efficiently and in one line

Tags: file, powershell, parsing, powershell-2.0

Windows .rdp files store values like so:

```
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofile:i:1
```

I can successfully parse these files and add them to an object as in the following example, except **not every .rdp file has every field here**.

```
foreach ($Path <# to RDP file #>) {

  $RDPFileObject = "" | Select-Object -Property "Gateway Usage", "Gateway Profile"

  $RDPFileObject."Gateway Usage" = (Select-String 
        -Path $Path -Pattern "gatewayusage:[a-z]:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
  $RDPFileObject."Gateway Profile" = (Select-String 
      -Path $Path -Pattern "gatewayprofile:[a-z]:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value

}
```

Thus, because I try to index using `Matches.Groups[1]` in one line, I often get

> Cannot index into a null array.

I can obviously check each `Select-String` with an `if` statement before indexing, but this will be wildly inefficient because I want to parse the entire file.

Is there a one-line solution to only trying to index the `Matches` array if the value exists, or a better way to add these properties to `$RDPFileObject` altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but it will parse the sample data to a PS Object in one line:

```
$RDPFileObject = New-Object PSObject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData ((Get-Content $Path | Out-String ) -replace '(.+):(.+)','$1=$2'))
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening here, where/how this beats the efficiency of my code, and how this would address capturing indexing null values?

Comment: It does a more or less direct conversion of the file content into PS Objects.   That should let you use PS pipeline operations like Where-Object and Select-Object to filter and manipulate the data using those objects, and would hopefully eliminate the whole array indexing issue.

Comment: ++ for a clever and elegant approach, though it needs tweaking for v2 (`-Raw` is PSv3, and the regex should be `'([^:]+):[^:]+:(.*)'`).
@AlwaysQuestioning: How this solution compares in performance you'd have to investigate, but it parses the _entire_ RDP file
into key-value pairs that are converted into a custom object, delegating the parsing to `ConvertFrom-StringData`, which bypasses the null-indexing issue altogether.

Comment: @mklement0 - good catch on the -Raw.  Replaced that with pipe through Out-String, which should make it V2-compatible.  The posted regex worked with the sample data provided, but may need to be adjusted if that's not representative of all the production data.

Comment: @mjolinor Production data is just 8 or more properties that need to be added to that same object that identify 8 more lines like the two I posted. I'll give it a try and come back.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Your `(.+):(.+)` regex parses `gatewayusagemethod:i:2` into `gatewayusagemethod:i`, and `2`; `([^:]+):[^:]+:(.*)` doesn't include the (presumably unwanted) `:i` part in the property name.

Comment: You may want to tack a second `-Replace` after your first one. A property listed is `username`, which very well may contain a value like `DOMAIN\User`, and `ConvertFrom-StringData` uses backslash as an escape character, so you want to add `-Replace '\\','\\'` just after your existing `-replace` operator. Oh, and a side note, the :i indicates the value is an **I**nteger. There is also :s for **S**tring values.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer may be of interest for its approach to avoiding the indexing-into-a-null-array problem.

For the specific problem of parsing an entire RDP file into key-value pairs converted to a custom object, see [mjolinor's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745217/45375).</sup>

I don't know how much overhead it adds, but if you're confident that the only reason that the command may fail is the lack of a match, you can use a `try` / `catch` block as follows:

```
$RDPFileObject."Gateway Usage" = try { (Select-String 
    -Path $Path -Pattern "gatewayusage:[a-z]:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value } catch {}
```

---

Generally, though, you'll get much better performance if you read the input file *once* in your loop body, *as a whole* into a *variable*, and then use `-match` and `$Matches` repeatedly with that variable.

(Reading the file as a whole shouldn't be a problem with RDP files, because they are small.)

Comment: The `try-catch` will have the same overhead as an `if-else`. I will absolutely do your suggestion of reading the file and then parsing the variable. I liked your syntax earlier of `if { ...} else { $match}`. That seems more readable as well. Should I be using $match as a variable here instead of `Matches.Groups[1]`?

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning: The `if (Select-String ...) { $matches[1] } else { $null }` solution (since deleted) was arco444's, and it didn't work, because automatic variable `$Matches` is only populated when you use the `-match` operator, not when you use the `Select-String` cmdlet. However, if you do match against a variable with `-match`, you can use `if (.... -match ...) { $Matches.Groups[1].Value }`.